Is there a way to call an asynchronous function from a synchronous function in njs?
I want to call an async function from a sync function in a dialect of JavaScript known as njs (it's part of Nginx).
I'm using njs' js_set to call a JavaScript function I'm writing named get_obfuscated_token, and per the docs js_set wants synchronous code. get_obfuscated_token needs to compute a SHA-512 hash, which seems to mean:
result = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", msgUint8);

But it appears I can't await on crypto.subtle.digest from a synchronous function. I'm getting back: "http_authorization":"[object Promise]".
How can I call crypto.subtle.digest in a way that will keep js_set happy?
In the worst case, I could resort to a pure-JavaScript SHA-512 function (like perhaps https://github.com/emn178/js-sha512), and make sure it's synchronous. But I'd rather not do that if there's a way that'll mean less code to maintain and won't require a license review.

It's just a promise; async functions always return promises. To get the value a promise resolves to (if any), you either await or pass a callback to its then method.

This question is similar to: How can I access the value of a promise?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

TTBOMK, this question differs only in that it's on njs.  It does not appear to suffer from the ideological purity problems of some Javascript interpreters, so perhaps it has a solution to such an issue?

I seem to be hearing that using a global would be the only way to get around this when using crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512")?  It seems like using a closure is insufficient too?  That, or use a synchronous library that can compute SHA-512's?

https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples/tree/b0d9e19e177f9a5bf86571085597626d53af17a4?tab=readme-ov-file#setting-nginx-var-as-a-result-of-async-operation. Promises are part of "pure JavaScript".

I tried a lexical closure, but no dice.
njs purportedly has a way of doing this asynchronously (instead of js_set), but I don't know what it is.

https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples?tab=readme-ov-file#setting-nginx-var-as-a-result-of-async-operation says there's a way of doing this (with something other than js_set), but it seems a little cagey about how.

There is a way of doing this, and it is njs-specific.
Not only is this sometimes a good idea, in this case it's a requirement.
js_set in nginx always passes an "r" argument.
At the end of your async function that is called by js_set, you need to call r.setReturnValue(result).  This returns "result" in a way that is usable by js_set.
